# Make form fields wider in Django+Bootstrap

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how I can make the form inputs themselves take up the same portion of the second column; I want the labels to be in one column and the inputs to take up the same percentage of the second column

[image: current form]

Here is my code in my HTML template:

```
<form method="POST" class="form mt-3 mb-3">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form  %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="{{ field.name }}" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right mb-3"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a css class and add the css class for the field on Form class. Please have a look on the following example.

```
class CustomerRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(label='Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control huge', 'placeholder': 'Name or Company Name *'}))
email = forms.CharField(label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control huge', 'placeholder': 'Email *'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Apply new css class "same-width" in your style tag

.same-width:{
    width: 300px;   
}


<form method="POST" class="form mt-3 mb-3">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form  %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="{{ field.name }}" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="same-width">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right mb-3"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```